# Can I use the Squeeze theorem with sequences of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

For example if I know that $f_n(x)\leq g_n(x) \leq h_n(x)$ for all $x$, then can I say that $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)\leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n(x) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(x)$? If yes, what kind of limit would $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n(x)$ be? The uniform or the pointwise limit?

Comment: That would be the pointwise limit. It's straightforward from the definition.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I would say the uniform limit since it applies for all $x$ right?

Comment: This is not true, unless the left and right limits are equal.  The middle limit may not exist.

Comment: No it's _not_ the uniform limit! it's: for a _fixed_ $x$, $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)\leq\lim_{n\to+\infty}g_n(x)\leq\lim_{n\to+\infty}h_n(x)$ (provided, of course, as @RRL mentions, that the limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty}g_n(x)$ exists).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf But the statement is for all $x's$

Comment: @RRL Ok, thanks! And if it's so ie right and left limits are equal, the limit is the uniform or the pointwise, what do you think?

Comment: For the _uniform_ limit, you'd need the _sequence of functions_ $(h_n-f_n)_n$ to approach _the nil function uniformly._ Being true _for all $x$_ (which means, for all _fixed_ $x$) is far from being enough to claim uniform limit.

Comment: What's the nil function?

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = x$, $h_n(x) = 3x$ and $g_n(x) = [2 +(-1)^n]x.$ The inequality is true but the middle sequence oscillates.  Yes -- you need the left and right sequences to converge uniformly to the same limit to get uniform convergence in the middle.

Comment: It's the constant function equal to $0$.

Comment: @RRL Thank you very much :)

Comment: Uniform convergence of the left and right sequences to the same limit function  is a sufficient condition for the middle sequence to converge uniformly.